I am getting "Module Not Found" error in NodeJs
Whenever I am trying to run my js file, this is showing:
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\labanya\Downloads\COLLEGE\hackathon\first.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

I tried copying the path and putting it at the environment variables but its not working.

Does this file exist? How are you importing it?

Function.executeUserEntryPoint shows that Node.js was trying to execute the main file you specified, but it encountered an issue.check filename, file location and file permissions.
